# Launch skype app in C#

Tags: c#, android, skype

I want to launch skype app in C sharp code for android app. Like we launch in native android as

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.raider");
startActivity( LaunchIntent );
```

How do we achive this in C#? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are doing the same as in java, just need to massage a bit for the Mono c# implementations. assuming that you are doing this inside the Activity.

```
var intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.raider");
StartActivity(intent);
```